# Upgrading Drupal 7.43 to 8 error: Source database is Drupal version 8 but version 7 was selected

Tags: migrations, upgrading

I am new to Drupal, but I am trying to upgrade a site with the version 7.43 to 8, flowing these steps: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/upgrade/upgrade-using-web-browser

After installing the Migrate modules and defining the source site, I have the following error message:

> Source database is Drupal version 8 but version 7 was selected.

In my old site's database, the drupal_version table is empty.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it. 
It was caused be an update on PHP, that caused blank pages or “white screen of death” (WSOD) in the admin, too. 
After updateing to 7.59, everithing was OK.
This article helped me: https://www.drupal.org/node/158043